# How to check number exist in int?

Tags: c#, int

I have some int value its name is `number`. I have other int value its name is `x`. I want to know is `x` exist in `number` or not. Currently I convert number to string() and use string.Contain(x) method. I think this is not a good way, it does boxing and performance is hurt.

Are there a better way to do this?

Additional information:
`number` may be one or more digit, for example, 12345. `x` is always one digit.

Comment: Please give examples. Is `number` always a single digit? Is `x` actually a single integer in string representation, or could it be multiple numbers (e.g. comma-separated)?

Comment: Converting `int` to `string` is not boxing. How did you identify that the `int` to `string` conversion is the bottleneck?

Comment: This method seems as good as any assuming that, by "contains", you mean the string version of one number appears within the string version of the other number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a bad method. The only alternative I can think of is something using repeated divisions and modulus operators which may well be slower due to the quantity of those operations.

I'd stick with what you have unless there's a *serious* performance problem.

---

Based on your additional information:

> `number` may be one or more digit, for example, 12345. `x` is always one digit.

I would opt for the following (pseudo-code):

```
def numContains (number, digit):
    if number == 0 and digit == 0:
        return true
    while number != 0:
        if number % 10 == digit:
            return true
        number = number / 10
    return false
```

The first `if` is required since you don't enter the `while` if you pass in a `number` of `0` and you still have to catch the case where both `number` and `digit` are `0`.

Otherwise, you just continue to check the least significant digit of `number` against `digit`, and divide `number` by 10 each time.

If a match is found before `number` reaches zero, it contains the digit. Otherwise it doesn't.

This will probably be faster than your string solution, since it will have to do similar operations to create the string from the integer and then do the string compare on top of that.

But, as with all optimisations, *measure, don't guess!*

---

And, now that I have access to my VS2008 development box, her's some C# code for it:

```
// Function: containsDigit, returns whether non-negative number holds a digit.
//       In: num, the integer to check.
//           dgt, the digit to look for.
//      Out: Boolean representing whether digit found in number.
//    Notes: Digit is coerced to a single digit.

Boolean containsDigit(UInt32 num, UInt32 dgt) {
    dgt = dgt % 10;                // silently force contract compliance.
    if ((num == 0) && (dgt == 0))  // Zero contains zero.
        return true;
    while (num != 0) {             // While more digits in number.
        if ((num % 10) == dgt)     // Return true if rightmost digit matches.
            return true;
        num = num / 10;            // Get next digit into rightmost position.
    }
    return false;                  // No matches, return false.
}
```

Comment: Then again, how many arithmetic calculations would match up to how many string comparisons? ... ... I'll shut up now :)

Comment: And exactly that is what matters when it's about extreme performance :)

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't use boxing, but it does create objects.

Using strings is a pretty good solution, and unless you need really exceptional performance you should just stick to it.

You could solve it numerically. Then you first need to find out how many digits there are in `x` so that you can use modulo to mask out a part of `number`. Then you can loop and check different parts of `number` for `x`:

```
int mask = 10;
while (mask <= x) mask *= 10;
bool found = false;
while (number >= mask) {
  if (number % mask == x) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
  number /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If x is single digit:

```
for (int n = number; n > 0; n /= 10)
{
    int digit = number % 10;
    if (digit == x) return true;
}
```

If x is multi-digit:

```
int xd = 0;
for (y = x; y > 0; y /= 10) xd++;

for (int n = number; n > 0; n /= 10)
{
    int digit = number % xd;
    if (digit == x) return true;
}
```